Is this the correct way to go about determining correlation between upstream and downstream temperature?
I am new to stats and R in general, so please bear with me. I have been trying to find an answer to this question for about the past week and have spent a ton of hours researching but am still confused as to how best to go about it.
I was tasked with determining the effect of dam releases on downstream temperature. I have a large data set of temperature loggers at various points downstream from the dam. What I want to find is to what extent does water release from the dam then effect downstream temperature. I would expect this to decrease as you progressively go downstream. At first, I determined the correlation in the temperature between the sites and the gauge at the dam release (which serves as my independent variable). The correlation ended up showing no significant change between the closest site and the farthest site from the dam. So correlation does not solve my answer.
After asking around, it seems that an effect-size analysis is the best way to go about it. Someone mentioned plotting the downstream temperature on the y and the gauge temperature on the x axis and then putting a Gaussian bump over top the scatter plot and using the covariance to determine the effect-size? I would like to know if this seems like an effective way to solve my question. I have never done this analysis and the research I have done has confused me. I also do not know how to fit a Guassian bump or what he means by that because the scatterplot does not seem to show a normal distribution to me. Any help would be much appreciated. I have included the scatterplots for the nearest (S4) and farthest site (S11) downstream. Not sure how to quantify the difference in effect-size using these scatterplots.


It is not clear on your objective.  For me the first thing to try is plotting time along the x axis and temperature on the y-axis.  This should give you an estimate of how long it take the water to flow from point 1 to 2 to 3, etc
